# How can I read buffer data from the type script?(Solana)

Tags: node.js, typescript, solana

How can I read buffer data from the type script?

I want to use the public key to get all the token lists I own.
I'm trying to get this, but an empty array of objects is being returned.

```
import {Connection, Keypair} from "@solana/web3.js";

const Solana = new Connection("https://api.testnet.solana.com/","confirmed")
const getInfo = async () => {
    const recentInfo = await Solana.getEpochInfo()
    const DEMO_FROM_SECRET_KEY = new Uint8Array([
       223, 119, 171,   5, 237, 138,  42, 140, 176, 163,  74,
      107,  25, 143,  90,  97, 250, 158, 203, 102, 238,  19,
       77, 228, 211, 238, 147, 149,  40,  50, 211, 155,  51,
      207,  14,  53,  86, 230, 164,  27,  14, 202,  78, 181,
      185, 250,  16,  52, 134, 242,  96,  16,  12,  67,   2,
      178, 106, 241, 156, 212,  11, 150, 114,  72])
    const keypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(DEMO_FROM_SECRET_KEY)

    console.log("=============get account info==============")
    async function fetchaccountdata() {
        const accountinfo = await Solana.getParsedAccountInfo(keypair.publicKey,"max")
        const accountinfodata =  JSON.stringify(accountinfo)
        const accountinfodata2 = JSON.parse(accountinfodata)
        console.log(accountinfo)
        console.log("=============get account info==============")
        console.log(accountinfodata)
        console.log(accountinfodata2)
    }
    fetchaccountdata()
}
getInfo()
```

Terminal is

```
accountinfodata = {"context":{"slot":94636033},"value":{"data":{"type":"Buffer","data":[]},"executable":false,"lamports":42784111360,"owner":{"_bn":"00"},"rentEpoch":231}}

accountinfodata2 = {
  context: { slot: 94636033 },
  value: {
    data: { type: 'Buffer', data: [] },
    executable: false,
    lamports: 42784111360,
    owner: { _bn: '00' },
    rentEpoch: 231
  }
}
```

The data of accountinfo object is empty array.
How can I read the information?

Comment: When you created the account, did you specify the storage amount for the data? Also, has a program written any data to the account?

Answer (score 1):

This call is fetching the account data for your wallet.  Your wallet only holds SOL, which is why the data is nothing!

If you want to get all of the token accounts that you own, you'll be better off using `getParsedTokenAccountsByOwner`: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/2a42f8a06edd4d33c6cda4d66add0a2582d37011/web3.js/src/connection.ts#L2310

Answer (score 1):

The buffer contains account info data in no particular format. Borsh has recently been established as a standard, though.

Example borsh serialization from SPL:
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/program/src/state.rs#L128

Example borsh deserialization for metaplex metadata: https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/master/token-metadata/program/src/instruction.rs#L77-L78

If you aren't trying to decode metaplex metadata, you should look elsewhere for the schema, but follow the same principles of the code. If you know the account isn't using borsh, then it's up to you to decode it.

Visit the solana tech discord for more information/help.
https://discord.com/channels/428295358100013066/517163444747894795/917412508418068510